# Expression evaluation problems in C++

Tags: c++

See the following code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int read(){
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    return a;
}
void print(int a, int b){
    printf("%d %d", a, b);
}
int main(){
    print(read(), read());
}
```

The result of the output transitions the order of the numbers, it isn't that C++ call function operation ',' behind?

Comment: Please take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Here is a nice list of [C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Subexpression evaluation is in general not ordered.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: Also, what part (besides that header file) is really "C++"? That looks more like pure C.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is also valid C++. C++ is a multiparadigm language, one of those is C-style programming

Comment: @M.M That's why I put C++ in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, in C++, the order of evaluation of subexpressions is [unspecified](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). Check out the link for more discussion, and some exceptional cases.

The C++ standard says:

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators
>   and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.[...]

The compiler may decide which argument of `print` (in your example) to evaluate first, based on efficiency or some other considerations. You should *never* rely on the order.